# Given a pseudo-random number sequence, find the equivalent lcg generated one

Tags: math, random, lcg

Given a pseudo-random number sequence S, is there an equivalent lcg (linear congruential generator) generated sequence S' that respects the relative order of S, and if so is it possible to compute the parameters a, c, m and seed?

For example, the following sequence, S:

1,     2,     4,     3

has as a possible equivalent lcg generated sequence (a = 16807, c = 78125, m = 2 ^ 31 − 1) the following S':

207560540,  956631177,  2037688522, 1509348670

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.